# MacBook 2,1 OS X 10.6.8 - Boot screen loop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

My  MacBook2,1 is stuck in a loop on boot screen. It flashes from *?Folder*, to an also flashing net recovery globe, and every so often an Apple logo for a few seconds, but never actually boots into the OS.

After an extensive internet search, the only results were to use the Mac OS X (command-R) recovery process.

I’ve tried everything I could find online regarding MacBook recovery, but they all refer to a globe to network restore, but I have yet to see a flashing globe like what I'm experiencing.

This MacBook is the only one I have, so if possible I need this fixed.

How can I go about fixing this, or should I just give up?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your question is at risk of being closed because it's very difficult to understand.  Please see [ask] for info on asking questions then do your best to clearly describe your hardware, the problem you're having, and what you've tried to resolve it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the age of your MacBook (it's 12 or so years old), it's highly likely your hard drive has died.

There is also the possibility that something else could be wrong with your MacBook, so there is the risk that you'll end up spending money on a new hard drive only to find that you still run into problems.

However, if this is a MacBook that you've been using without problems until now and it's your only option in terms of having a computer you can use, then replacing the hard drive on these is not hard to do. See this [iFixit guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Core+Duo+Hard+Drive+Replacement/282) on the process involved to determine if you feel comfortable doing this.

As for the type of hard drive you'll need, your MacBook uses a Serial ATA (SATA) hard drive interface, so buying a hard drive that suits will be easy to do. Just make sure you remember to get an internal drive that is 2.5" (not a 3.5" drive designed for desktop computers).

Once you've replaced the drive you'll need to reinstall Snow Leopard (i.e. Mac OS X 10.6) from scratch (or reinstall from whatever discs came with your MacBook). Of course this requires that your optical drive is still working fine, so if it's not you'll need to look at other options such as using macOS Recovery.

Comment: The only Recovery available for this model Mac is the [OS X Recovery Disk Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202294).  To create the recovery disk, Lion (OX X 10.7.x) would first have to be installed with a functioning built-in Recovery System. (In other words, an internal Lion recovery partition.)

Comment: It is obvious now that the reason I’m getting nowhere is I assumed recovery would work on snow Leopard but it was introduced in the lion upgrade 10.7 so I’ll order a copy and install fresh

Comment: Thx so much hope my next question gets  the same kind of prompt answer this is a great little info flow